# Conditional expectation; how to find E[xy] when E[x|y] is known?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In my studies for an exam which I have on Friday I have come across this assignment from last year in which the following question is asked:

"Let $E[x] = \mu$ and $var[x] = \sigma^2$. If $E[x \lvert y] = a + bx$, find $E[xy]$ as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$."

Now in this assignment of last year, an answer by a group of students from that year was provided:

"The law of total expectations states $E[xy] = E[E[xy \lvert x]]$. By linearity of conditional expectations, $E[E[xy \lvert x]] = E[xE[y \lvert x]]$. We get

$E[xy] = E[E[xy \lvert x]] = E[x[E[y \lvert x]] = E[x(a + bx)] =$ ...."

Where at the end they simply write out the expression and then input the given $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. I'm not sure whether this is correct. First of all, I'm not sure whether I understand correctly how $E[xy] = E[E[xy \lvert x]]$ follows from the law of total expectation. I thought that it might be as follows:

$E[E[XY \lvert X = x]] = E[xE[Y \lvert X = x]] = \sum_x xE[Y \lvert X]P[X = x] =$
$ \sum_x \sum_y x y P[X = x \lvert Y = y]P[X = x] =  \sum_x \sum_y x y P[X = x, Y = y] = E[XY].$

However I would like to know if that line of reasoning is correct.

Secondly I don't see why $E[y \lvert x] = E[x \lvert y]$ would have to be true. Could anyone tell me whether this is correct and possibly explain why it is correct or what is correct if it isn't? Mathematically, intuitively, or both?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you write $Z$ for $XY$ (note $Z$ has nothing to do with _normal_ random variables), then would you agree that $E[Z\mid X=x] = E[xY\mid X=x] = xE[Y\mid X=x]$?  If so, then note that when $X$ equals $x$, the _random variable_ $E[Z\mid X] = E[XY\mid X]$ takes on value $xE[Y\mid X=x]$ and so the _random variable_ $E[XY \mid X]$ is $XE[Y\mid X]$ (and is a function of $X$ as it shoud be),.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct:
$$E[XY] = E[E[XY\lvert X]] = E[X[E[Y \lvert X]] = E[X(a + bX)].$$

By linearity of the expectation operator, we get
$$E[XY]=aE[X]+bE[X^2].$$
Using the fact that $E[X]=\mu$ and $E[X^2]=\sigma^2+\mu^2$, we get

$$E[XY]=a\mu+b(\mu^2+\sigma^2).$$

Comment: So $E[Y \lvert X] = E[X \lvert Y]$? How?

Comment: Of course not, where did you get this? $E(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$, while $E(X|Y)$ is a function of $Y$. I copied the first line  from your post.

Comment: You write that $E[Y \lvert X] = a + bX$, however, it is given that $E[X \lvert Y] = a + bX$.

Comment: Oh right I didn't notice that. It must be a typo. $E(X|Y)$ would have to be a function of $Y$, not $X$. If your assigned problem has written that $E(X|Y)=a+bX$, it must be a typo that should read $E(Y|X)=a+bX$.

Comment: As you were typing that the same idea came to me... I checked the original assignment file and indeed it was a typo. Now excuse me as I go stab myself with a pen while realizing I wasted 40 minutes thinking about this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't feel too bad--it happens to the best of us!